# Can CLR Profiler be used for profiling ASP.NET applications?

Tags: asp.net, iis, clrprofiler

Can CLR Profiler be used for profiling ASP.NET applications?

Comment: [MSDN: Profiling ASP.NET Applications with CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650691.aspx#scalenethowto13_topic5)

Comment: +1 This is what I was looking for however I don't know how can I mark this one as Answer. There is no check icon with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *used* to be possible (albeit not quite straight-forward, as I remember it). I have not tried the new one yet, but I would be quite surprised if that one did not handle it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible:

1. Start the program
2. Check/Uncheck Allocations and Calls as needed (note: you must have Allocations checked for calls to work).
3. Verify the Target CLR Version
4. File>Profile ASP.NET
   [image: Selecting Profile ASP.NET from the menu]
5. Once the IIS server has restarted, load the pages you want profiled.
   [image: Window which shows after IIS restarts and before an ASP.NET page is loaded]
6. Click "KILL ASP.NET" to stop the profile.
   [image: The Kill ASP.NET button]
7. Analyse the output

After you kill the profiler, the start button changes to "Start ASP.NET" so you do not have to go back into the file menu to start the profiling.
[image: Shows the final state of the control]